# Version Control/Configuration Management for Avaya PBXs?

Tags: version-control, vector, configuration-management, pbx

Here at Acme Widgets, we use an Avaya 8xxx series PBX.  Some of the Vectors that are coded into the PBX are super important, in that if they're changed in the wrong way, pretty much all of our telephony arena applications and features go haywire (IVR, CTI, CRM, and ACD).

There have been some recent discussions where we've disagreed as to how certain vectors have been coded in the past, and there have also been increasing situations where multiple different folks are making changes to these highly important components.

I've asked my PBX administrator if there is something equivalent to a Configuration Management/Version Control tool for PBX Vectors, and he doesn't believe there are.  What do y'all think?  Has anyone ever heard of such a thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a VCS specialized in PBX Vector. It actually depends on the internal format of such an object.

According to "[Configuring Avaya Definity PBX](http://www.intl.firstclass.com/help/Voice%20Services/Analog%20Installation/S003D2E6A-003D2E76)":

> vectoring uses a table outlining the coverage path for each station, instead of each station being configured individually (hunt-to configuration). Depending upon your Avaya Definity software version, the table can support anywhere from 13 to 32 routes or more per vector.

That means:

- if it is text-based, any VCS tool can store deltas between 2 versions of a vector
- what will be more important as to the choice of a Version tool is how the update is done: from a single location, or with agent through the country. In the former case, a centralized VCS (Subversion, Perforce, ...) is enough, with a direct access to a single repository storing the vector deifnitions. In the latter case, a DVCS (Mercurial, Git, ...) is needed, in order for each agent to work with the full local repository, and then synchronize it between them.